# Python copy folder with Windows Progress Bar

Tags: python, windows, file, copy

Is there a way to initialize a Copy command with Python on Windows.
I want to get a Progress window just like I would when using Copy / Paste in the explorer:

[Windows Progress Bar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1JbnK.jpg)

So basically Python only starts the process and Windows runs it.

I know there are other ways to the a Progress bar within python but that's not what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Call [`SHFileOperation`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/shellapi/nf-shellapi-shfileoperationa). You could perhaps use [this](https://github.com/arsenetar/send2trash/blob/master/send2trash/plat_win_legacy.py) as a starting point...